# text floating up into div above

Tags: html, css, layout

I have product grid laid out, with nested div's for the content inside the box, and then a div  bellow the box for details. but for what ever reason, my text keeps floating up inside the div above it.

[image: photoshop mock-up]

```css
body{
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 960px;
}
#big-divider{
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 15px; 
 color: white;
 font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 32px; 
}
#sub-stamp{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
 max-width: 287px;
} 
#header{
 margin: 25px;
}
#header > img:nth-child(2){
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top:-10px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 746px;
}
h2{
 font-family: avenir next, arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-style: oblique;
 font-size: 33px;
 text-align: right;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin:0;
 margin-top:-42px;
 line-height: 100%;
 color: #31bbac;
 
}
h1{
 font-family: avenir next, arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 800;
 font-size:41px;
 background-color: #0033a0;
 padding-top: 4px;
}
.box{
 position:  absolute;
 display: block;
 border: solid 3px #0033a0;
 height: 310px;
 width: 288px;
}
.price span{
  font-family: avenir next, arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 800;
 background-color: #0033a0;
 color: white;
 font-size: 25px;
 padding: 0px 5px;
}
#info{
 position: inherit;
 bottom:0px;
 right: 0;
}
.box img{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
 max-width: 252px;
 padding: 15px;
}
#product-grid{
 margin: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>YES TEST</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yes-style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header" >
  <img src="img/top-shor-line-logo.png">
  <img src="img/top-stamp-sale.png">
  <h2>
   CoJack Tables 
   </br>
   Are Super Cheap
  </h2>
 </div>
 <div id="big-divider">
  <h1>
   Save big on the things that you need!
  </h1>
  <img id="sub-stamp" src="img/tables.png">
 </div>
 <div id="product-grid">
  <div class="offer">
   <div class="box">
    <div class="price">
     <span>&#36<span>170.69</span></span>
    </div>
    <img src="img/cojack.jpg">
    <div class="price" id="info">
     <span>INFO</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="details">
   <h4>
    CoJack Lift Table
   </h4>
   <span class="product-number">
    195.1038.00
   </span>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not exactly sure where in the provided image the problem would be. If you could try and point it out in the image that would help.
Also, try and avoid code-dumps.

Comment: This issue is you're using `position: absolute;` for `.box` which causes the element to take up no space in the document flow.

Comment: I suspect the problem is either the `position: absolute` style in the box class or that there is no product-number class in the style sheet. The absolute position removes the box from the regular flow of the document so the missing class needs to set position relative to the box.

Comment: sorry for the code dump, I just wanted to provide the most amount of information, as i'm not really sure where the kink is, but i'll slim it down.

The part that i'm talking about is the image box description. "cojack lift table, 195 etc.

Comment: I'll try those other suggestions, and get back to you all, Thankyou for your help!

Comment: @jac you were right, i switched it to inherent and its all good now. I cant vote it up because of my level :( if anyone can do this for me that would be great

Comment: Your going to have to wrap `.offer` and `.details` in a parent container, something like `.product` if you're going to repeat the markup like your linked mock-up.

Comment: Try `float: left; clear: both`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the text COJACK TABLES ARE SUPER CHEAP to right bottom corner.

You just do one thing add **position:relative** style for ***#header***,
Then you need to add

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
bottom:0:
```

for h2 element